# Quelle serait une autre manière plus élégante d’écrire ce qui se trouve dans les informations plus bas?

Tags: expressions, choix-de-mot, expressions-idiomatiques, formulation-idiomatique, formulation

Il n’a pas tout particulièrement aimé le récit qu’il a fait de son aventure rocambolesque au camping *Plein Bois* dans lequel il critique avec force l’usage répandu de drogues dures par les campeurs.

Merci.

Comment: … et il serait plus élégant de dire « … les informations ci-après ? »

Comment: C'est un style comme un autre, sauf « Il n’a pas tout particulièrement aimé … » qui ressemble à du Gogole translaté — Essayer la lecture lente puis rapide … ça aide quand on se sent seul :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Par exemple :

> Il n’a pas particulièrement apprécié le récit rocambolesque  de son
> aventure au camping "Plein Bois", où il critique ouvertement la
> consommation de drogues dures par les campeurs.